# Surjectivity (onto) for isomorphism definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I have two books on algebra where one makes the definition of isomorphism to be a bijective homomorphism, while the other makes it as an injective homomorphism.

I am doing the exercises from one book and learning from the other (not optimal I know), and so I am wondering what definition is considered the convention.

If both are conventionally okay, is something lost by removing the surjective part of the bijection and if so what? I realise it's a rather uninteresting question, but if someone has the time I would appreciate the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the author writes injective homomorphism or maybe injective **epi**morphism (which are the surjective homomorphisms), as conventionally isomorphism includes also surjectivity as I know it?

Comment: It is old notation to call an isomorphism and injective homomorphism.  Most "modern" books require isomorphisms to be bijective.  The one place that I've seen the other definition is in Herstein (and that annoys me).  One origin for this confusion is that an injective homomorphism an isomorphism onto its image.

Comment: Aha. It is indeed Hersteins book I am using. Could you explain the last part about the confusion? I didn't quite follow.

Comment: A homomorphism is always surjective onto its image (by definition).  If it is also injective, then it is a bijection and so it is an isomorphism onto its image.

Comment: But wouldn't that suggest that it is superflous to call an isomorphism a bjiective homomorphism? Or in other words that the definitions are in fact the same?

Comment: Remember that an image is not the same as the codomain.  What it means is that there is a *subgroup* of the codomain which is isomorphic to the original group.

Comment: It is apparent I have some studying to do. But this was all very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" definition of an isomorphism is a homomorphism which has an inverse homomorphism. For many algebraic structures this is the same as a bijective homomorphism, but not always, see lhf's remark. There is the [“Injectivity Implies Surjectivity Trick”](https://lydianrain.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/the-%E2%80%9Cinjectivity-implies-surjectivity%E2%80%9D-trick/). This means that it is often enough for an isomorphism to have an injective homomorphism.

Comment: The correct definition of an isomorphism is a homomorphism that has an inverse homomorphism.
For groups, rings,  vector spaces, and other algebraic structures, an isomorphism is the same as a bijective homomorphism, but this is a theorem. For an example where this equivalence fails, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677607/why-are-the-isomorphisms-and-bijective-morphisms-not-identical-in-the-category-o).

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two groups $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4$ (the integers modulo $2$ and modulo $4$).  We can write $\mathbb{Z}/2=\{0,1\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4=\{0,1,2,3\}$.

In modern notation, we would not say that these two groups are isomorphic because there is no bijection between them (as they are different sizes).  There is, however, an injective map from $\mathbb{Z}/2$ to $\mathbb{Z}/4$ given by $0\mapsto 0$ and $1\mapsto 2$.  In this case, the subgroup $\langle 2\rangle\subseteq\mathbb{Z}/4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

In older notation, an injective map might be called an isomorphism because the image of the map, in the example above, the image is $\langle 2\rangle$, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$.