# Why are the isomorphisms and bijective morphisms not identical in the category of Pos?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\text{Pos}$ be the category of partially ordered sets and monotonic functions. A morphism $f$ is called an isomorphism if there is a morphism $g$ such that $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are identity morphisms. On the other hand a bijective morphism satisfies this condition,while it has been asserted that they are not identical. Can you explain what is happening? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take two elements, $0$ and $1$, and define the poset $X$ with $0\leq 1$ (and the reflexivity conditions), and $Y$ the poset only with $0\leq 0$ and $1\leq 1$ (i.e., we can't compare $0$ and $1$ in $Y$. Then the identity $Y\to X$ is a bijective morphism, but not an isomorphism (what would be it's inverse, and why is it not a morphism?).

The problem with posets is that we can't always compare elements.

If we were in the category of *totally ordered* sets, then any bijective morphism is in fact an isomorphism. What We did above was just take a simple poset ($X$) and weaken its structure a little bit (and obtain $Y$).

Comment: Thanks. my problem lied in the wrong hypothesis that all monotonic functions were morphisms.

Comment: @user318848 Of course every monotonic functions is a morphisms of $\mathrm{Pos}$ : this is the definition of a morphism in the category of posets. Your error lied in the belief that the **set-theoretic** inverse of a monotonic function is necessarily a **monotonic** function.

Comment: @Pece That was exactly what I falsely believed.

Comment: For future readers confused like me: a poset is a partially ordered set